# jquery load div after page load

Tags: jquery, html, load

Actually what I am looking for loading is loading the page first and then a div with lots of data. So, I want to load the main page first and then body div content using jQuery function with some delay.

What is the simple way of implementing this..?

```
 <div id="container">
      <div id="header">navigation</div>
      <div id="body" class="body">Body</div>
      <div id="footer">footer</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.get('ajax/page.php', function(data) {
    $('#body').html(data);
  });

});
```

Comment: #body div needs to be loaded with some delay. How to add that

Comment: you can put a timer on it if you like, but remember that this won't fire until the entire initial page has loaded and the document is considered "ready" on the client side.

Comment: how can i disable a input button until the external page is loaded..?

Answer (score 3):

The shorthand version:

```
$(function(){
 $("#body").html();
 //...
});
```

If you want to do it after an interval

```
function load(){
 $("div").html(...);
}
$(function(){
  // Interval of 5 secs.
  setInterval("load()",5000);
  //http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

The ready function is called when page is fully loaded. You can load your div in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done:

```
function newContent()
{
    $("#navix").load("new1.php");
}
$(function(){
  // Interval of 5 secs.
  setInterval("newContent()",5000);
  //http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
});
```

It works great ;)